# Half of the inputs aren't written to excel - exceljs and nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, excel, exceljs

I'm new to programming so I don't have a lot of experience and can be making some dumb mistakes. But I'm stuck with a problem that I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I have a website with a form -  that form after submitted should be stored in a database (which happens successfully) and written in an Excel file for later linkage with some vba. I'm exporting the same values to the DB and Excel, so if they're in the DB I assume they are valid but only about half of them appear in the Excel.
That half is corresponding to a different tab on the form but I tryed changing one of the inputs for the first tab and nothing changed.

I'll post here my code:

```
exports.sendForm = (req, res) => {
    
    console.log(req.body);

    const { name, length, spacing, structureType, H, h, R, b1, B, b3, b4, t11, t12, t2, t3, openN, openS, openE, openW, Lr, Lf, country, windRegion, snowRegion, seismicRegion, terrainType, A, munic, sea } = req.body;
    

        form.query('INSERT INTO form SET ?', {Name: name, Length: length, Spacing: spacing, StructureType: structureType, NorthColumnHeigth:H, SouthColumnHeigth:h, RidgeHeigth:R, RidgeDistance:b1, Width:B, CantileverLength:b3, CentralColumnDistance:b4, NorthBracingLengthNB:t11, NorthBracingLengthSB:t12, CentralBracingLeftLength:t2, CentralBracingRightLength:t3, OpenFaçadeNorth:openN, OpenFaçadeSouth:openS, OpenFaçadeEast: openE, OpenFaçadeWest:openW, RoofPurlinsSpacing: Lr, FaçadePurlinsSpacing: Lf, Country: country, Wind: windRegion, Snow: snowRegion, Seismic: seismicRegion, Terrain: terrainType, Altitude: A1, Municipality: munic, DistanceToSea: sea}, (error, results) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(results);

            // row 1 is the header.
            const row = worksheet.getRow(2);

            row.values = {
                name: name,
                length: length,
                spacing: spacing,
                structureType: structureType,
                H: H,
                h: h,
                R: R,
                b1: b1,
                B: B,
                b3: b3,
                b4: b4,
                t11: t11,
                t12: t12,
                t2: t2,
                t3: t3,
                openN: openN,
                openS: openS,
                openE: openE,
                openW: openW,
                Lr: Lr,
                Lf: Lf,
                Country: country, 
                Wind: windRegion, 
                Snow: snowRegion, 
                Seismic: seismicRegion, 
                Terrain: terrainType, 
                Altitude: A1, 
                Municipality: munic, 
                DistanceToSea: sea,
                };

            workbook.xlsx.writeFile('C:\\Users\\Ana\\Desktop\\study.xlsx');
            
        };
    });
};
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKTNo.png)

Columns J-S are meant to be empty, but not the ones after.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Ana

Comment: The error is here: "I assume they are valid", you should debug the code, and make sure they are valid !

Comment: @Luuk yes I agree, but if the same values appear in the DB shouldn't they appear in excel aswell?

Comment: @Luuk I managed to debug and the input are being recognized as 'undefined' by exceljs but not for the DB. Any idea why?

Comment: It is pretty unclear when you say "only about half of them appear in the Excel". Which half? the upper half, or the lower half?  Focus on 1 of the fields, which has a value in the DB, and not in Excel, and debug that one.   I cannot be of much help because I do not see what you have in your database and/or in the Excel sheet.

Comment: @Luuk It's from country and beyond. I'll do as you suggest! Thank you

Comment: @Luuk thanks so much for your insights. I managed to find out - of course it was a stupid mistake. Because I did it in different days I didn't realise that from Country forward I was actualy writing the header name instead of the key name!